# Looking for a ruby on rails wiki application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wiki

I am looking for a ruby on rails wiki application. which i can download and modifiy according to my needs. i tried instiki but is there anything apart from that ? Which has basic formtting and version histories features implemented ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps) is the place to go for this. I recommend [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) for your needs. It is a simple wiki system built on top of Git that powers GitHub Wikis.

Look at [Irwi](https://github.com/alno/irwi) and [Perwitiky](https://github.com/jm/perwikity). Both are inactive now, but Irwi seems to be more up to date and is Rails 3 ready.

Comment: i am looking for something that is rails specific and works on the rails MVC structure.

Comment: yes but i need the entire mvc of that, which i am not able to find

Comment: What do you mean by 'entire mvc' and of what?

Comment: well, i want to see how the controller,models and the views are setup. along with helpers,routes. basically the entire app

Comment: Then you should to to their respective Github pages and look at the source code. They are gems, easily customizable and moreover easy to extend the functionality they provide. Not a drop-in functionality types. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i know.but i am looking for something more recent..anyways thanks.i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook Wagn http://wagn.org/  Quoting Ward Cunningham "The freshest thing in Wiki since I coined the term".

Pretty great as a Wiki and searchable database, and soon to be even more of an OO application platform in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the RubyGems site

[Wiki2Go](http://rubygems.org/gems/Wiki2Go) could do the job for you.

FYI: [Here](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=wiki) are the search results

Comment: didnt help me needs. most of them are outdated and i am not able to set them up with rails 3

Comment: Which gem does http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/ run?

Comment: dokuwiki or something like that. i think its php.. well..thats tragic :p